# Java socket client to server on different network.

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, socketserver

My question: 
How do I establish a connection from a client on one network to a server on another network in Java?

Background:
I created a simple client and server that communicate fine using localhost, or on two different computers using the same network. I connect using the inet address (e.g. inet 10.xx.xx.xx) and a port number (e.g. 55123).

I realize that my client cannot find my server because they are on different networks, i.e. the ip address and port do not provide enough info for the client to find the server.

```
sock = new Socket(10.xx.xx.xx, 55123);
```

What am I missing for my client on the other network to find my server?

Thank you very much for your help!

James

Comment: IP and Port are the only necessary information. However you have to make sure to use the actual IP of the host machine and that there is no proxy or any other device obfuscating it.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: It was quite a while ago.... yes I did come up with a solution, but I don't know if it was related to the above:
I created a proxy server on the receiving device so the client could easily connect to that. Then that server relayed messages to where they needed to go on the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not Java specific.  This is really about how IPv4 / IPv6 networking / addressing works.

The `10.0.0.0/24` network range is reserved for private networks; see Wikipedia's ["Private Network"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) article.

If the server has a `10.xx.xx.xx` address, AND your client is on a different network, then it is simply not possible for your client to connect directly to the server.  Your client's network simply cannot route packets to the server's network.

(Indeed, there are millions of networks around the world that use `10.xx.xx.xx` addresses.  Your server's IP address is not unique ... except in the context of the private network it is attached to.  So which of the many possible servers with IP of (say) `10.42.42.42` servers should the client's packets be routed to?)

Possible solutions:

- Give the server needs a public IP address.
- Set up 3rd server with a public IP address that is also on the private network,  and run some kind of service to tunnel traffic to the server.  A VPN is one way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Server must have public IP so that client can connect to it. Or you need [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) over those networks (so server is reachable from client's network).